# Partitioning a large binary file using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, binaryfiles

Trying to process a large binary file using PySpark, but always getting OutofMemoryError. Tried all possible ways such as increasing executor/driver memory, repartitioning the rdd. Will a single large binary file gets partitioned in spark? If not, how can we process binary files. The binary file which I am using currently is more than 2GB.

Comment: You need to give more details. Couple comments: 1. It's not that big. 2. It can even be processed with one node. What is binary? How do you read it?

Comment: all data is binary at some point.  binary gets interpreted into text or image or something.  Can you tell us more about your binary format?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Basically it is a tar file which contains some bunch of medical images called dicom(it is a standard medical imaging format) files. As it is a binary file, I guess single file cannot be partitioned right? And from this link, got to know that a block cannot be more than 2GB (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyfHUNnMutg&t=15s). I am using python plugins for reading tar and dicom file.